# git track ignored folder

Tags: git

I excluded a specific folder from git with .gitignore. Today I need to track the files inside, but seems that deleting the line in .gitignore doesn't work.
I tried to do `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged -R folder` but -R doesn't work, when I do `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged folder` he tells me `fatal: Unable to mark file media` because he is expecting a file not a folder.

So how do I track these files ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: This is somewhat of a "is it plugged in" question, but: did you try `git add folder`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you got step one right to get rid of the line that excludes it in the .gitignore file. Commit that. Now `git add path/to/your/file` and commit. The file should now be tracked.

If it still isn't, check that you didn't set up a exclude pattern in the config that may be doing this.

Comment: Ok so I need to check that because the commit doesn't want it.

Comment: are you sure you committed the change to the .gitignore file? can you see it in the patch view with `git log -p -1` if it's the last commit you made?

Answer (score 1):

If you get `fatal: Unable to mark file media`, the file probably isn't in the repo. Try `git ls-files -o`. This will tell you what files are not in the repository. If it's listed on there, then you have to do `git add folder`. If it causes you any problems, you can maybe add `git add -f folder` to force an add despite ignore settings.